# Java String quote delimiter

Tags: java, string, delimiter

Is there any way in Java to use a special delimiter at the start and the end of a String to avoid having to backslash all of the quotes within that String?

i.e. not have to do this:

```
String s = "Quote marks like this \" are just the best, here are a few more \" \" \""
```

Comment: Anyone knows if this idea (verbatim strings) is on the table for Java 7?

Comment: if you like backslashing your special characters, you should try regular expressions ;)

Comment: I think `@` is used in C# to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such option. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

No - there's nothing like C#'s verbatim string literals or Groovy's slashy strings, for example.

On the other hand, it's the kind of feature which *may* be included in the future. It's not like it would require any fundamental changes in the type system. I'd be *hugely* surprised for it to make it into Java 7 this late in the day though, and I haven't seen any suggestions that it'll be in Java 8... so you're in for a long wait :(

Comment: And unless it's a completely brain-dead implementation, it won't break existing syntax either.

Comment: There was a proposal for 'multi-line Strings' put forward as part of Project Coin; later discussion on the list pointed out that escaped Strings would be more useful. Nothing came out of it, AFAIK, not least because the original proposal was, to put it politely, 'a little sparse'. http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-February/000034.html

Answer (score 2):

The only way to achive this is to put your strings in some other file and read it from Java. For instance a resource bundle.

Comment: Storing literal strings directly in code != language portability.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible as of now, May be NOT in future also.

if you can give us what and why you are loookng for this kind of feature we can defnitely Suggest some more alternatives