# Cannot add elements into the List Salesforce

Tags: list, collections, salesforce, apex

Please tell me why I cannot add these elements into the List. Please find the attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYDxI.png) for the error.

```
public class PracticeOnLists {

    List<String> myList = new  List<String>();
    myList.add('element1');
    myList.add('element2');
    myList.add('element3');
    myList.add('element4');
    System.debug('The List is' + myList);
    System.debug('The size o the List is ' + myList.size());
}
```

Comment: change single quotes to double quotes `myList.add("element1");`

Comment: Single quotes are used for characters, say 'a' 'b' '#'. Double quotes for strings, say "I'm a string"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java String quote delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492189/java-string-quote-delimiter)

Comment: There's a pending edit. Review it and accept it. And also state whether the question is about **Java** or **Apex**

Answer (score 0):

There are major problems in your code.

- `List` is an interface, so you cannot create objects of an interface. You'll have to create an object from a child class of `List`.
- In Java you need double quotes(`"`) to create a String.
- And you cannot write statements just inside a class. They must be in a method or a block.
- If you want to get viewable outputs I suggest you use `System.out.println()` since there's no method called `debug()` in the `System` class.

So this should be your code

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

void addToList() {
    myList.add("element1");
    myList.add("element2");
    myList.add("element3");
    myList.add("element4");
    System.out.println("The List is" + myList);
    System.out.println("The size o the List is " + myList.size());
}
```

Comment: "Do it like this" it not an answer, an answer means explanation

Comment: WAIT TILL I EXPLAIN... EDITING IN PROGRESS

Comment: The code mention in the question is an Apex Code. Not Java. And in Apex it is possible to create an List<String> because there its not an Interface like in Java.
Also the: System.debug('The List is'+myList); is a typical debug from Apex and has nothing to do with Java

Comment: @utm then why the hell the question refers a java tag?

Comment: It also refers to Salesforce Tag. I haven't ask the question...so I have not clue. I just know that the question looks very like related to Salesforce/Apex and not to Java.

Answer (score -3):

The problem is that you have to do this inside a method. Single quotes are correct-double quotes are wrong in **Apex(Salesforce) NOT Java**.

```
public void doItHere() {
     myList.add('element1');
     myList.add('element2');
     myList.add('element3');
     myList.add('element4');
}
```

Comment: Nope, nope and nope